# Open strings and branes

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions, branes

In string theory, open strings are attached to branes. What does "attached" mean? Do they just interact with the branes, or are they related to them in some other way?

Comment: Homework? Someone flagged this as homework?

Comment: @JohnRennie Strange, isn't it?

Comment: "Attached" just means that if you parametrize the endpoints of the string by $x(\tau)$ (where $\tau$ is proper time), then $x(\tau_{0}) \in W_{Brane}$ for all $\tau_{0}$, where $W_{brane}$ is the worldvolume of the brane in question.

Comment: "Attach: to fasten or fix something in position, esp. in relation to something else". What is attached to D-branes is endpoints of strings.

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah That is, it is not just an interaction, we can say that the string "belongs" to the brane.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян or, you know, "attached" to the brane :)

Comment: @Kosm Well, yes, if you consider that they are attached in such a way that their separation from the brane is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Attached means that the endpoint of the strings are quite literally confined to move on the [brane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-brane). Strings and branes are related via dualities, look for references of S and T dualities.

The fact that we call the theory string theory is a historical accident, we should really call it brane-theory (or at least string-brane theory) since both entities are fundamental extended objects in the full non perturbative theory.

Comment: That is, the string somehow "belongs" to the brane?

Comment: Kind of. Open strings cannot leave the brane, unless they interact and are emitted as closed strings.

Comment: And where do they emitted if there is nothing but branes?

Comment: If the brane is 3D, they have other 6 dimensions (in superstring theory).

Comment: Check the picture here for more intuition: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208600/is-electron-positron-annihilation-to-two-gravitons-forbidden/208797#208797

Comment: That is, they are emitted into extra dimensions? What if the extra dimensions are compactified?

Comment: Correct. There is nothing particular about compact dimensions, the same applies.

Comment: And in background-independent models, where will the particles be emitted?

Comment: These are unrelated questions, I would suggest you to have a look at A first course in string theory by Barton Zwiebach to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks. That is, for the formulation of any string theory, the existence of a background space-time is necessary?