# Can open Strings interact and lead to a String which is not fixed to a Brane?

Tags: string-theory, branes

Would it be possible that two open Strings interacted with each other and could they theoretically then leave their Brane?

Comment: Yes, they can leave as closed strings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and also the reverse process is possible:

[image]

These are called mixed open-closed string interactions. See [Is electron/positron annihilation to two gravitons forbidden?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208600/is-electron-positron-annihilation-to-two-gravitons-forbidden/208797#208797).